# Working with NavigationView items within a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigationview

I'm trying to execute the next code inside the onCreateView method of my Fragment:

```
 if (displayedPalabra!=null){
        setCardAttributes(displayedPalabra);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) layout.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
    }
```

But gives me the next error when executing:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.Menu
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.getMenu()' on a null
>   object reference

My question is: Is the layout from the Fragment not being able to access the NavigationView From the MainActivity and thus retrieving a null value? Do I have to somehow access it some other way? The code should be self-explanatory, im just trying to set this Fragment's item as checked at the NavigationView Menu of my app... usually I do it from the MainActivity to put the default one but this Fragment is called from another fragment this time...

Comment: You can create a method inside your activity to switch fragments and use only that. Make it public, and access it from inside fragments aswell

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your fragment layout doesn't contain R.id.nav_view, because it is inside activity layout, not fragment. Get navigation view from your activity using getActivity().

Comment: Thanks... i just realized how dumb my error was, my problem is i was using code from the main activity... I used the getActivity() and solved, thanks for pointing out. As soon as i can i will mark ur answer as accepted.

Comment: While you can access navigation view like this, this is probably not correct approach. Your fragment should not know about navigation view. Use some listener/notification mechanism to report activity or logic controller that selected item was changed.